# Emacs mode-line highlight during macro definition

Tags: emacs, modeline

Is there as simple way to have a clear indicator when I'm defining a keyboard macro (`kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter`), e.g. by changing the mode-line background or something similar?

The "Def" indicator is hard to parse out and sometimes not visible due to many minor-mode indicators/narrow screen.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the standard functions bound to `f3` and `f4` and modified them by adding `my-modeline-face-function`, and rebound those keys to the new functions.  You can change the colors of the faces in `my-modeline-face-function` to suit your needs.  I chose to use `cond` because you may find that you have other similar needs for the various major and minor modes, and you can insert similar conditions for those modes.  [For example, you could do this for isearch-mode, or calculcator-mode, etc.]

The value returned by `face-remap-add-relative` is stored in a custom variable that I named `my-face-remap-cookie`, which in turn is used at the end of the macro recording phase as an argument to the function `face-remap-remove-relative`.

```
(defun my-kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter (arg)
  "Record subsequent keyboard input, defining a keyboard macro.
The commands are recorded even as they are executed.

Sets the `kmacro-counter' to ARG (or 0 if no prefix arg) before defining the
macro.

With \\[universal-argument], appends to current keyboard macro (keeping
the current value of `kmacro-counter').

When defining/executing macro, inserts macro counter and increments
the counter with ARG or 1 if missing.  With \\[universal-argument],
inserts previous `kmacro-counter' (but do not modify counter).

The macro counter can be modified via \\[kmacro-set-counter] and \\[kmacro-add-counter].
The format of the counter can be modified via \\[kmacro-set-format]."
  (interactive "P")
  (if (or defining-kbd-macro executing-kbd-macro)
      (progn
        (my-modeline-face-function)
        (kmacro-insert-counter arg))
    (kmacro-start-macro arg)
    (my-modeline-face-function)))

(defun my-kmacro-end-or-call-macro (arg &optional no-repeat)
  "End kbd macro if currently being defined; else call last kbd macro.
With numeric prefix ARG, repeat macro that many times.
With \\[universal-argument], call second macro in macro ring."
  (interactive "P")
  (cond
   (defining-kbd-macro
     (if kmacro-call-repeat-key
   (kmacro-call-macro arg no-repeat t)
       (kmacro-end-macro arg)))
   ((and (eq this-command 'kmacro-view-macro)  ;; We are in repeat mode!
   kmacro-view-last-item)
    (kmacro-exec-ring-item (car kmacro-view-last-item) arg))
   ((and arg (listp arg))
    (kmacro-call-ring-2nd 1))
   (t
    (kmacro-call-macro arg no-repeat)))
  (my-modeline-face-function))

(defface my-recording-macro-face
  '((t (:background "yellow" :foreground "black")))
  "Face for `my-recording-macro-face`."
  :group 'my-faces)

(defvar my-face-remap-cookie nil
"The return value of `face-remap-add-relative` is a Lisp object that
serves as a `cookie`; you can pass this object as an argument to
`face-remap-remove-relative` if you need to remove the remapping later.")
(make-variable-buffer-local 'my-face-remap-cookie)

(defun my-modeline-face-function ()
"Doc-string."
  (require 'face-remap)
  (cond
    (defining-kbd-macro
      (setq my-face-remap-cookie
        (face-remap-add-relative 'mode-line 'my-recording-macro-face)))
    (t
      (face-remap-remove-relative my-face-remap-cookie)
      (setq my-face-remap-cookie nil))))

(define-key global-map [f3] 'my-kmacro-start-macro-or-insert-counter)

(define-key global-map [f4] 'my-kmacro-end-or-call-macro)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. An improvement could be storing the defaul mode-line colors somewhere and resetting them back aftre F4. I really like the idea to use it also for isearch-mode!

Comment: `face-remap-add-relative` returns a value that can be stored -- e.g., in a buffer-local variable.  That value can later be used by the function `face-remap-remove-relative`.  This has the effect of meeting your needs to effectively restore the default value of `mode-line`.  The revision has been incorporated into the above-answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
(setq minor-mode-alist
      `((abbrev-mode " Abbrev")
        (overwrite-mode overwrite-mode)
        (auto-fill-function " Fill")
        ;; not really a minor mode...
        (defining-kbd-macro ,(propertize " Def" 'face 'highlight))))
```

All I did was tweak the original code from `bindings.el`, replacing `" Def"` with the value of `(propertize " Def" 'face 'highlight)`.

Use whatever face or face spec you like, in place of `highlight`.

Comment: @user673592: I wonder, did you even try it? Seems a lot simpler - just highlights the standard `Def` indicator, which is what I thought you requested. But perhaps I misunderstood the question?